# Sql Server - Fastest way to get number of times value changed for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rdbms

I'm writing sql queries to display different types of results as per following requirments :

1. Display record who's value changed from **1 to 0**, maximum times in given timestamp
2. Display record who's value changed from **1 to 0**, minimum times in given timestamp
3. Display top 10 records who's value changed from **1 to 0**, maximum times in given timestamp

Sample Data :

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| DeviceId | CaptureTime | SensorValue |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
|  DC001   | 02/01/2017  |      0      |
|  DC001   | 02/02/2017  |      1      |
|  DC001   | 02/03/2017  |      0      |
|  DC001   | 02/04/2017  |      1      |
|  DC001   | 02/05/2017  |      0      |
|  DC001   | 02/07/2017  |      1      |
|  DC001   | 02/08/2017  |      0      |
|  DC001   | 02/10/2017  |      1      |
|  DC001   | 02/01/2017  |      0      |
|  DC001   | 02/01/2017  |      0      |
|  DC002   | 02/02/2017  |      1      |
|  DC002   | 02/02/2017  |      0      |
|  DC002   | 02/02/2017  |      1      |
|  DC002   | 02/02/2017  |      1      |
|  DC002   | 02/02/2017  |      1      |
|  DC002   | 02/03/2017  |      1      |
|  DC002   | 02/03/2017  |      0      |
|  DC002   | 02/03/2017  |      0      |
|  DC002   | 02/03/2017  |      1      |
|  DC002   | 02/03/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/03/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/03/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/03/2017  |      0      |
|  DC003   | 02/03/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/03/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/04/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/05/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/06/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/07/2017  |      1      |
|  DC003   | 02/08/2017  |      1      |
|  DC004   | 02/09/2017  |      0      |
|  DC004   | 02/10/2017  |      0      |
|  DC004   | 02/11/2017  |      1      |
|  DC004   | 02/12/2017  |      0      |
|  DC004   | 02/12/2017  |      1      |
|  DC004   | 02/12/2017  |      1      |
|  DC004   | 02/12/2017  |      1      |
|  DC004   | 02/12/2017  |      1      |
|  DC004   | 02/12/2017  |      1      |
|  DC004   | 02/12/2017  |      1      |
|  DC005   | 02/12/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/12/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/12/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/12/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/14/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/14/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/14/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/14/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/14/2017  |      0      |
|  DC005   | 02/14/2017  |      0      |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have created bellow common query for all three requirements :

```
DECLARE @HoursBack  INT
        , @MinMax   VARCHAR(3)
        , @TopRows  INT

SELECT  TOP (@TopRows) COUNT(TD1.DeviceId) PickedNoOfTimes, ItemName -- I have removed table to get ItemName to simplify this query
FROM    tTrayDetails AS TD1
WHERE   TD1.SensorValue = 0
AND     TD1.CaptureTime > DATEADD(HOUR, -@HoursBack, GETDATE())
AND     TD1.SensorValue <> (
                                SELECT  TOP 1 SensorValue
                                FROM    tTrayDetails TD2
                                WHERE   TD2.CaptureTime < TD1.CaptureTime
                                ORDER BY TD2.CaptureTime DESC
                            )
GROUP BY    TD1.DeviceId
ORDER BY    CASE WHEN @MinMax = 'Max' THEN COUNT(TD1.DeviceId) END DESC
            , CASE WHEN @MinMax = 'Min' THEN COUNT(TD1.DeviceId) END ASC
```

This query works for all three requirements, by just setting different values of  @HoursBack, @MinMax   and @TopRows variables.

*Here is the values to set for my three requirements* :

1. @HoursBack = 24, @MinMax='Max', @TopRows=1
2. @HoursBack = 24, @MinMax='Min', @TopRows=1
3. @HoursBack = 24, @MinMax='Max', @TopRows=10

**Now Problem is** : This query takes around 40 Sec to execute, only for 14K records on testing environment.

On production environment daily 2-4K records will get added, so this query execution time will increase.

How I can change the query to run faster with large amount of data.

Comment: Take a look at the `LAG() OVER ()` window function, with this function you can select the previous value and determine whether the given row is a change or not.

Comment: Shouldn't your sample data include time?

Comment: What's your SQL Server release? 2012 supports LAG/LEAD.

Comment: Smells like homework

Comment: Thanks @Aquillo, I'll check 'LAG()' function, I heard it first time. Can you please suggest me any good source to check that ... If possible ...

Comment: Sorry @SqlZim, "CaptureTime" is DateTime column and contains full date and time value.. I just truncated time for simplicity .. I thought it doesn't matter .. But yes it's DateTime value if it really matters ...

Comment: @dnoeth My SQL Server is 2014 (12.0.2000.8)

Comment: Any indexes? Consider using a [covering index](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/). Note that SQL Server 2005 and later versions support [included columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) as well as composite indexes.

Comment: @Shrikant it matters if it gives us unique rows instead of a bunch of duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will count only those rows where SensorValue changed from 1 to 0:

```
WITH cte AS
 (
   SELECT DeviceId,
      -- previous row = 1 and current row = 0
      CASE WHEN LAG(SensorValue)
                Over (PARTITION BY DeviceId
                      ORDER BY CaptureTime) = 1
                AND SensorValue = 0
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END AS ChangeFlag
   FROM tTrayDetails AS t
   WHERE ....
 )
SELECT DeviceId, Count(*)
FROM cte
WHERE ChangeFlag = 1
GROUP BY DeviceId
```

Now apply your `TOP`/`ORDER BY` ...

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
declare
    @topRows int = 2,
    @minMax nvarchar(3) = 'max',
    @hoursBack int = 1000,
    @now datetime = getdate();

;with _raw
as (
    select
        DeviceId,
        case when SensorValue = 0 and lag(SensorValue) over (partition by DeviceId order by CaptureTime) = 1
            then 1
            else 0 
        end as Val
    from tTrayDetails
    where
        CaptureTime > dateadd(hour, -@hoursBack, @now)
)
, _combined
as (
    select
        DeviceId,
        sum(Val) as Val,
        (case when @minMax = 'min' then 1 else -1 end) * sum(Val) as Ord
    from _raw
    group by
        DeviceId
)
select top(@topRows)
    DeviceId, Val
from _combined
order by
    Ord, DeviceId
```

And the same again as test script:

```
create table #tTrayDetails
(
    DeviceId nvarchar(128),
    CaptureTime datetime not null,
    SensorValue int not null
)

insert into #tTrayDetails(DeviceId, CaptureTime, SensorValue) values
    ('DC001', '2017-01-01 01:00:00', 0),
    ('DC001', '2017-01-01 02:00:00', 1),
    ('DC001', '2017-01-02 01:00:00', 0),
    ('DC001', '2017-01-03 01:00:00', 1),
    ('DC001', '2017-01-04 01:00:00', 0),
    ('DC002', '2017-01-01 01:00:00', 0),
    ('DC002', '2017-01-01 02:00:00', 0),
    ('DC002', '2017-01-01 03:00:00', 1),
    ('DC002', '2017-01-01 04:00:00', 1),
    ('DC002', '2017-01-01 05:00:00', 1),
    ('DC002', '2017-01-01 06:00:00', 0),
    ('DC003', '2017-01-01 06:00:00', 0)

declare
    @topRows int = 2,
    @minMax nvarchar(3) = 'max',
    @hoursBack int = 1000,
    @now datetime = getdate();

;with _raw
as (
    select
        DeviceId,
        case when SensorValue = 0 and lag(SensorValue) over (partition by DeviceId order by CaptureTime) = 1
            then 1
            else 0 
        end as Val
    from #tTrayDetails
    where
        CaptureTime > dateadd(hour, -@hoursBack, @now)
)
, _combined
as (
    select
        DeviceId,
        sum(Val) as Val,
        (case when @minMax = 'min' then 1 else -1 end) * sum(Val) as Ord
    from _raw
    group by
        DeviceId
)
select top(@topRows)
    DeviceId, Val
from _combined
order by
    Ord, DeviceId


drop table #tTrayDetails
```

Comment: Thanks @pkuderov .. It's good solution, but I have used dnoeth's solutions as it work same with less script  .. But your solution really helped me out in one another scenario, because it returns groups with changed values as well as returns groups with change count '0'. Indirectly you helped me in two queries ....

Comment: @ShrikantBhusalwad you're welcome :) Select dnoeth's solution as "Accepted", pls.